# Using RegEx in replace and test method in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using test and replace method for detect and replace tags in the text
but replace method returns the text associated with tag, while should just return text without tag!
why?

my jquery plugin :

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
insertTag: function(Tag){
    var pattern = new RegExp("\[("+Tag+")\](.*?)\[\/("+Tag+")\]","gi");

    return this.each(function (i) {
        var sel,ptrn;

        if (document.selection) {
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = '['+Tag+']' + sel.text + '[/'+Tag+']';
        }
        else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
            this.focus();
            var startPos = this.selectionStart, endPos = this.selectionEnd;
            sel = this.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
            alert(sel); // show seleced text for debug ing!

            if(pattern.test(sel)){
              txt = sel.replace(pattern,"$1");
              alert(txt); // show replaced text for debug ing!

              this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + (txt) + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);

            }else{
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + ('['+Tag+']' + sel + '[/'+Tag+']') + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);

            }
        }
    })
}
```

});

this section for remove tag in selected text if existed :

```
if(pattern.test(sel)){
              txt = sel.replace(pattern,"$1");
              alert(txt); // show replaced text for debug ing!

              this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + (txt) + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);

            }
```

But it does not work properly....

for example :

```
txt = $("#txt");
```

txt.insertTag(b) :

```
[b]some text[/b]
```

txt.insertTag(b) :

```
[]some text[/b]
```

While the return to "some text"

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: when using `RegExp` constructor you need to escape the \ into \\

Comment: var pattern = new RegExp("\\[("+Tag+")\\](.*?)\\[\\/("+Tag+")\\]","gi");
after using replace method, return "b"

Comment: You are escaping `[` not enough and you are escaping `/` unnecessarily (too much here). I suggest you inspect `pattern` (with `console.log(…)`, not `window.alert(…)`) before you run the program.

Comment: i using \\ in pattern but replace method return "b" string :(

Comment: i changed \ to \\ in pattern, but replace method return only "b" string :(

Comment: Thanks, first level of my problem in create simple text editor is solved! ;)